# Keeping .git/HEAD

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I want to use the `git-branch` npm module to detect my branch in the code, but Heroku doesn't show the .git folder, so `git-branch` displays an error.
Is there a way to make that I can access that file?
If not, can I use a workaround, like copying the file and then restoring it, or stuff like that?
I'm auto-deploying from GitHub a Node.js app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way. Heroku will not send the `.git` folder to the build.
Even if that folder were kept, you would always see the `master` branch though, as it's always what you push to.

However, you can still retrieve the pushed GIT commit (not the branch) using the [dyno metadata](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata) feature, which will set environment variables with various informations about your app. `HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT` will be the commit you deployed.

Comment: Thanks, but I only need the branch :\
Would it be a stupid thing to commit a file in every branch that tells me its name?
When I merge the branches then I keep only one of them.
Doesn't seem really smart to me but it's the only solution that I found.

Comment: When you deploy a branch, is that a review app? If so, you could get the HEROKU_APP_NAME variable, which isn't the branch but you could deduce it from that.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#heroku_app_name-and-heroku_parent_app_name